# Find a non-normal operator that is similar to a normal operator

Tags: matrices, operator-theory

Find a non-normal operator that is similar to a normal operator

**My Solution:**

For non-normal operator consider, $$T=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix} .$$ and For normal operator consider, $$I=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} .$$

Can we say that: they are similar?

Comment: why-1 down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let we take,
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 2&3\\0&5\end{bmatrix} $$
and
$$B=\begin{bmatrix} 2&0\\0&5\end{bmatrix} $$
Here, $B$ is self-adjoint matrix, so it is normal also!
And $A$ is non normal matrix.
Clearly, $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Comment: Vats Y,Good answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, these matrices are not similar. In particular, the only matrix that is similar to the identity matrix is the identity matrix itself: for any invertible matrix $S$, $SIS^{-1} = SS^{-1} = I$.

**Hint:** You are on the right track. An upper triangular matrix will be normal if and only if it is diagonal. On the other hand, a matrix will be similar to a normal matirix if and only if it is diagonalizable.